# Mathematical computing rules-of-thumb

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, big-list

Does there exist a simple, cheatsheet-like document which compiles the best practices for mathematical computing? If not, could someone respond with a list of the top best practices? E.g., it would include items like:

1. For large numerical vectors `x`, instead of computing `x^2`, compute `x*x`. This speeds up calculations for reasons...(?)
2. To solve a system $Ax = b$, never solve $A^{-1}$ and left-multiply $b$. Lower order algorithms exist (e.g., Gaussian elimination)

BACKGROUND: I'm finding papers where programmatic implementations are quite different from what derived analytic expressions would suggest. Different factorings, expansions, and approximations are used all over the place. I don't think it's simply arbitrary. But the problem is that I have no sense of WHY they're doing what they're doing. I think a cheatsheet-like document would help with this.

UDPATE: I did find a nice numerical analysis cheatsheet [here](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cs421-cheat-sheet4.pdf). But I'm looking for something quicker and dirtier

Comment: What do you mean by the first example (computing $x*x$ instead of $x^2$ for a large numerical vector $x$)?

Comment: @Henry: e.g., in R, even though `x^2` and `x*x` return the same, length-n vector, the former is computationally more burdensome. 

Comment: This question is much too broad (every software system is different, and there are a LOT of these...), so I am voting to close until this is big-list/community-wiki

Comment: Yes, this is actually too broad as Igor points out. Even though rules of thumb encode a compressed version of wisdom and experience acquired over the years, they are no substitute for system (architecture, hardware, etc.) and algorithm specific tuning.

Comment: I am afraid the answer is "No, you really have to take at least that basic course in numerical analysis, or at least browse a book on the subject".

Comment: I suspect item 1 means "Compute x DOT x, instead of |x|^2", and that the reason this is faster is that the computation of |x| proceeds by computing sqrt(x DOT x)...

Comment: @Sridhar. It's not a dot product. It's element-wise multiplication. 

Comment: So maybe I should ask this specifically for, say, R over on the StackOverflow board?

Comment: @brianjd: yes, R on StackOverflow, Mathematica on StackOverflow, Maple on StackOverflow, Macsyma on StackOverflow, MuPad on StackOverflow, Matlab on StackOverflow....

Comment: "...old Prince Lasgere of Tsort asked me how he could become learned, especially since he hadn't got any time for this reading business. I said to him `There is no royal road to learning, sire' and he said to me `Bloody well build one or I shall have your legs chopped off. Use as many slaves as you like.' A refreshingly direct approach, I always thought. Not a man to mince words. People, yes. But not words." 

Comment: in case anyone wonders, from "Small Gods" by Terry Pratchett, page 208 in a paperback edition of 344 pages. 

Comment: Thanks to those providing constructive feedback. I have to admit I'm bothered by some of the responses though. I suppose there's no substitute for knowing set theory, but we go ahead and learn to count. I suppose there's no substitute for knowing how the internal combustion engine works, but we go ahead and drive cars. Sure, knowing numerical analysis would improve my programming greatly, but I was inquiring about a few basic rules-of-thumb that would improve it marginally. I provided a couple examples that, for me, helped serve that end. I thought others might have some as well...

Comment: ...I was not asking anyone to be a slave. Maybe answers would have been too system-idiosyncratic and closing the question was the reasonable thing to do. But I don't think my question was a priori unreasonable. I may be reading some of these responses wrong, but they give me the feeling that academic elitism is alive and well here. 

Comment: Given that your questions seem to be at an undergraduate mathematics level, you would have a better experience at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions 
where such questions fit well. This is an elitist site in that it is for researchers in mathematics itself. If you ever get interested, the Pratchett book is quite good. 

Comment: @Will. Fair. I see in the first line of the FAQ that this is for "research level math questions". I wouldn't have asked my question here if I'd read that first. Thank you for the pointer. 

Comment: Rule of Thumb #1: Don't depend on rules-of-thumb!

Comment: @brianjd: I see (I was thrown by the mention of vectors, though I should've seen your earlier clarification). In that case, it's surely simply for the same reason that x^2 can be slower than x * x for single element calculations: the general procedure to compute x^y with arbitrary (possibly even non-integral) exponent y is presumably rather slower than the procedure to simply multiply two values (this latter operation probably being particularly primitively implemented in hardware).